# How to untar a file in hadoop hdfs

Tags: json, hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, tar

I have a lot of JSON files (1 MM) in the local directory. ANd I need to move these JSON files as it is to HDFS.

Created a tar which contains all the JSON files.

```
tar -cvf filename.tar local_folder_name
```

Moved the .tar file to hdfs directory

```
hdfs dfs -put filename.tar hdfs://nameservice1/user/hive/warehouse/dbname.db/table_name/
```

I need to extract all the files from the tar in hdfs and keep them as separate JSON files in hdfs. The reason I went with the tar option is to move a single file to hdfs rather than one file at a time for each file in the 1 MM.( Which is extremely slow and not sure if it will complete)

I tried the below option and few other variants of this.

```
hdfs dfs -cat hdfs://nameservice1/user/hive/warehouse/dbname.db/table_name/filename.tar | tar -x | hdfs dfs -put - /user/hive/warehouse/dbname.db/table_name/untar_dest
```

I see a new file named untar_dest in the hdfs directory but this is of size 0 and has nothing in it.

```
-rwxrwx--x+  3 hive hive          0 2020-05-15 21:23 /user/hive/warehouse/dbname.db/ctable_name/untar_dest
```

Something is not correct and I am not able to find a way to solve this.

How can I extract the files from .tar in hdfs?

Answer (score 2):

You can write simple java api, to untar using `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil`

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html

Few examples, you can find here

https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil/unTar